# Is there any way to avoid bloating the DOM with host elements using Angular?

Tags: angular

If I create an Angular component with the selector `app-child` and add that into the top level AppComponent component of a new Angular project. When I view the DOM in browser devtools I see

```
<app-root>
  <p>AppComponent</p>
  <app-child>
    <p>ChildComponent</p>
```

`app-root` and `app-child` appear to be Web Component custom elements that correspond to each Angular component's host element. These host elements are a source of annoyance to me for the following reasons.

1. If I break down a desired DOM model to one Angular component per element, then every Angular component contains an addtional host element basically doubling the number of elements in the DOM.
2. If I'm trying to create a complex flex based layout then I have a load of extra CSS to deal with to style the host element and then forward the effect of that to the topmost contained element in the component.
3. It breaks the correct semantics of my DOM. If I have one component containing a `ul` containing other components that whose topmost element is an `li` then instead of the semantically correct layout of `ul > li` I instead have these interspersed host elements.

It seems to me that none of this is an issue in React which does not create host elements and in which it is therefore possible to create a component graph that generates the exact DOM you desire.

Is there some way to avoid this that I'm not aware of, or is this not a real problem for some reason?

Comment: angular is a component-based framework, every component source code does not affect any other component (there is no relation between one component and another you are going to need dependency injection or service to make a relation between components)

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how your comment relates to the question.

Comment: Usually this is not an issue. However, you can prevent this by simply using attribute selectors that you can apply to any standard DOM element. For example, <div class=“flex” app-child >Whatever</div>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the attribute selector.
On your component anotation paramenters, use the selector like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[hello]',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`
})
```

And then, the component is used like this

```
<div hello name="{{ name }}"></div>
```

Or this:

```
<ul>
    <li hello name="{{ name }}">Item 1</li>
    <li hello name="{{ name }}">Item 2</li>
    <li hello name="{{ name }}">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

This way you won't have the app-child element on the HTML.

All possible selectors: https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector

Full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3jqrun?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Doesn't that just enable you to replace a host element of type custom element, with a host element with the type of a specific DOM element (in this case a div)? You're still left with an extra DOM element for every component and the problems that causes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But you can use it in a way that does not break the semantics of the DOM. I've updated my answer and the stackblitz code with an example of a unordered list. Note that you can also do this with the default selector ('app-child').

Comment: I see. You're right, technically that does work. But I don't like the fact that it requires the parent component to select the correct DOM element type for the child component in order to maintain semantic HTML. It's fragile in that for a component that is reused often someone is inevitably going to forget to do this. It completely breaks the correct encapsulation of the reusable component.